# How to plot 3d function using IlPanel c#

Tags: c#, plot, ilnumerics

I'm using Ilnumerics and now I would like know if it's possible plot in IlPanel function with two variables like f(x,y).

I have searched around internet but I have found nothing. Someone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up from version 3.3.2. 'ILSurface' allows the definition of a function of two arguments to be plotted as a surface:

```
private void ilPanel1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ilPanel1.Scene.Add(
        new ILPlotCube(twoDMode: false) {
            new ILSurface((x,y) => {
                return (float)Math.Sin(0.1f * x * x + 0.2f * y * y);
            })
        }); 
}
```

Result: 
[image: ILNumerics Surface based on a function of two variables]

Comment: But if I want plot a function tat I receive in input: for example the user put in a textbox Abs(x)+Abs(y) and then click draw. How can I draw the function?